# Can't mass-assign protected attributes with nested form and custom class name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I know a lot of people already had the same issue but I did not find a solution for my particular case. 
I have the following models:

```
class Invoicing::CommercialDocumentLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :commercial_document_line_details_attributes

  has_many :details, :class_name => "Invoicing::CommercialDocumentLineDetail", :foreign_key => :commercial_document_line_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :details
end
```

And

```
class Invoicing::CommercialDocumentLineDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :commercial_document_line_id

  belongs_to :commercial_document_line
end
```

I have a form to update a `CommercialDocumentLine` which allow a user to add some details:

```
= simple_form_for line do |f|

  ## some code here which works great

  = f.simple_fields_for :commercial_document_line_details do |fd|
    = fd.input :description
```

The problem is that I keep having the warning:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: commercial_document_line_details
```

Here is my console log :

```
"invoicing_commercial_document_line"=>{"article_id"=>"3", "unit_price"=>"200.0", "format_quantity"=>"2.0", "discount_rate"=>"0.0", "commercial_document_line_details"=>{"description"=>"awesome"}}, "commercial_document_id"=>"1", "id"=>"11"}
```

The fact is I'm a little confused on what's going on here: if I replace in my form

```
= f.simple_fields_for :commercial_document_line_details
```

by

```
= f.simple_fields_for :details
```

then the form won't be displayed. And if I replace

```
attr_accessible :commercial_document_line_details_attributes
```

by

```
attr_accessible :details_attributes
```

then I have the same error.

I'm certainly missing something here but I can't figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use `= f.simple_fields_for :details`, it's actually fetching the list of details for `f.object`.  For new objects, this is usually blank so you won't see anything.  This is the correct way to use `fields_for`.  You just need to build a detail in the controller using `@line.details.build` or in the view using `f.object.details.build`

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually you're right when I add `@line.details.build` in my controller I can now see ann associated detail but I keep having the same warning when I update a line... any idea?

Comment: did you should use `attr_accessible :details_attributes`?

Comment: Yes, like I said in my question, I tried both :details_attributes and :commercial_document_line_details_attributes, which give me the same error, and that I don't understand...

Comment: if you use `f.simple_fields_for :details`, you should receive a different set of params.

Comment: it perfectly works, I just forgot to change that. Thanks a lot for your time.